# IntelliJ Idea keep asking me to enter "Path to certificate" and "Certificate passphrase" when committing my code after I switched branch

Tags: intellij-idea, svn, version-control

IntelliJ Idea keep asking me to enter "Path to certificate" and "Certificate passphrase" when committing my code using SVN.

[image]

It was fine until I switched my branch to a new branch.

[image]

What IntelliJ want me to do?

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that I had to check "Enable interactive mode" in Version Control > Subversion.

Answer (score -1):

> what IntelliJ want me to do?

It prompts you to authenticate by providing your client certificate and its passphrase. You need to either provide this information to authenticate to the server and access the repository, or contact an administrator for assistance.